# How to disable/enable Jquery event by a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery event attached to a certain `id="myid"` & want to disable it by a `<button>` click & then afterwards re-enable via same `<button>` click & vice-versa for infinite times.

Comment: with attached, you mean with an event?

Comment: Please post the code you have. I assume by `code attached to id` you mean an event?

Comment: @charles : Yes! Its's a event.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan :  `$(function() {  $("div#myid").mousewheel(function(event, delta) { this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 206);   event.preventDefault();    });  });` is a horizontal scroll event for my div `<div id="myid"> ---data--- </div>`. I want to disable it, to able to make vertical scroll on `#my`, then re-enable to make horizontal scroll again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('button').toggle(function() {
    $('#myid').unbind();
}, function() {
    // attach your event
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/
http://docs.jquery.com/Events/toggle

Comment: Thank-You! Although I've used Small Java-script in my case but found this method best. (i.e. doing it with J-query way to enable/disable the J-Query Event; gives Cross-browser compatibility.)

Answer (score 0):

You can detach with off.

```
var fn = function() {
  alert('my function');
};

$('#myid').on('mouseenter', fn);

var enable = true;
$('button').click(function(){
  if (enable) {
    $('#myid').off('mouseenter', fn);
  } else {
    $('#myid').on('mouseenter', fn);
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/iyemij/1/edit